# Cómo comparo un String con un Vector?

Tags: c++, c++17

Tengo que comparar una entrada por teclado guardado en un string con un vector string que contiene muchas palabras (extraídas de un .txt). Cómo hago para que pueda comparar si la palabra escrita existe o no?

Este es el código que he probado de hacer, pero no funciona (es la primera vez que trato de hacer algo así, estoy en 1ro de Industriales):

```
void exist(string& introduce, vector<string>& otherW, vector<string>& urW) {
bool es = false;
for (auto it = otherW.begin(); it < otherW.end(); it++) {
    if (introduce.compare(*it) == 0) {
        urW.push_back(*it);
        es = true;
        cout << endl << "Esta palabra existe";
        break;
    }
    else {
        es = false;
    }
}
if (!es) { cout << endl << "No existe esta palabra."; }
```

}

(urW es un vector que quiero usar para almacenar las palabras que sí estén en la lista de las que se introduzcan, introduce es el string de entrada y otherW la lista de palabras)

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

PD: Si es necesario que pase todo el código pq el fallo pueda estar en otro lado lo paso, aunque es un poco largo.

Comment: Porque estas usando un vector y no una lista?

Comment: @ErnestoRincon Porque no sé qué es una lista, a menos que te refieras a un array. Apenas llevo 2 meses programando y la profesora no ayuda en nada XD, así que me las apaño como puedo para poder sacar el trabajo de fin de asignatura (tengo que hacer un Paraulògic en c++). A pesar de todo, creo que he encontrado el problema hace un momento.

Comment: Te entiendo. A mi me paso con una profesora también. Si encontraste la solución por tu cuenta y te funciona puedes compartirla ya que puede ser de ayuda para alguien mas. [Aqui](https://www.programacion.com.py/escritorio/c/listas-en-c#:~:text=Permite%20el%20recorrido%20de%20todos,ninguno%20y%20en%20forma%20ordenada.&text=Etc.,elemento%20siguiente%20de%20la%20lista.) ay información sobre listas.

Comment: El contenedor que sirve para comprobar rápidamente si contiene un elemento es [`std::set`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). Con su método [`find`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) puedes comprobar si la palabra se encuentra en el conjunto o no sin hacer manualmente la comparación.

Comment: @ErnestoRincon la pregunta es sobre C++, no creo que OP necesite implementar una lista enlazada. De hecho, si desea usar esr tipo de estructura, puede utilizar el contenedor [`list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)

Comment: [No veo ningún problema](https://ideone.com/VexGAZ). Por cierto, acostúmbrate a darle nombres descriptivos a las variables. No importa que sean largos, con el auto completado de los IDE es más fácil.

Comment: @Mateo Sí, ya vi que el fallo al final residía en otro void que tengo hecho. Sobre los nombres descriptivos, ya lo son. Entiendo que para otras personas a lo mejor no entienden lo que ponen, pero yo no tengo problema. Está todo escrito en mi jerga personal, con la que escribo a diario también. (introduce es lo que es, otherW son otras palabras, urW son tus palabras, es solo indica que existe, es decir lo que hace el void en sí).

Answer (score 0):

No reinventes la rueda, ya existen funciones en el estándar que te permiten saber si un contenedor de datos tiene un valor determinado.

```
const std::vector<std::string> palabras { … };

std::string palabra;
std::cin >> palabra;

const auto found = std::find(palabras.begin(), palabras.end(), palabra);

std::cout << "La palabra " << palabra;
if (found == palabras.end())
    std::cout << " no";

std::cout << " esta en la lista\n";
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVDLjsIwDDyTr7CyFyqxfACUSuzrtJ@wFzcNXUupUyUuF8S3d9PSUsTe7Bl7ZmzTtq@1MX3/QmxcV1nIyUcJFptCLVhCiOtH5GyN@PCIoKt9IPlNi4pYoEHidaYuamU8R4Eo1W53W8vHehKFFh2WASNcQB9LX2Pl9Qb0mzU2hLF8R8G2c4JD80ExEUwNWZaR/mzaYCMGQje0X1R3AYXO2KQJq@G6V2r1YDk77ifUEENRLOicGDvxcPIdV3C4xT8RV@s577a09XDi5n7B1iZ66bO7r/GdQJ6D/saZBD0ASxI6wXryOjwJZmr1JAPs9X9xsFEQLINDcJTqH05T176fvqr@AA)</kbd>.